# Как сохранять текстовые файлы Python в определённую папку?

Tags: python

```
users = {}
filename = 'phonenumbers.txt'
flag = 1

while flag:
    message = input("Enter kommand: ")
    
    try:    
        if message.lower().strip() == 'wr':
            user_name = input("Enter name and surname: ")
            user_phone = input("Enter user's phone: ")
            users[user_name] = user_phone
            
            with open(filename, 'a') as f_object:
                for key, value in users.items(): 
                    f_object.write(key + ': ' + value + '\n')
            
        elif message == 'pr':
            f = open(filename)
            while True:
                line = f.readline()
                if len(line) == 0: # Нулевая длина обозначает конец файла (EOF)
                    print("File is empty")
                    break
                print(line, end='')
        
        elif message == 'cl':
             with open(filename, "w"):
                pass
            
        elif message == 'exit':
            flag = False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        msg = "Sorry, the file " + filename + " does not exlist."
        print(msg)
```

Начал изучать Python по книге Abyteofpython там была задача сделать телефонную книгу, решил дополнить её так, что бы он сохранял текстовый документ в определённую папку. Может какие библиотеки есть для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = 'dir1/dir2/file.txt'
with open(file, 'w') as file:
    file.write()
```

Вся магия, просто указываете полный путь до папки.